# Webpack HRM does not update the view

Tags: webpack

I have a problem with webpack HRM. I am using hapi.js server to start the webpack. Webpack compile all the files (my application is multi entry). The application is using latest React 15.6. When I make a change in some of my React components, webpack start a rebuilding process.

When the process finish, in browser console I see the logs

[http://imgur.com/a/DDTQW](https://imgur.com/a/DDTQW)

ui/pages/Login/index.js ---> this is the file where I made a change

When I go to Network tab in DevTools in my Chrome I see the updates

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IiDA.jpg

But the view is not updated. Also I use react-hot-loader/webpack as a loader. After refreshing the page I see the changes/updates. My problem is how to re-render the view after I receive the changes/updates.

Thanks

Comment: could you show your code (package.json, webpack.config, app.js ,etc.. )

Answer (score 0):

@José Quinto Zamora

Sorry for the late answer, but I found why this happening. Actually it tooks me more than a week. Everything with the webpack configuration is ok. I am using webpack-hot-middleware and react-hot-reload. Top Component is AppContainer from 'react-hot-reload'. On every change in every component I get the same error -
 full reload is needed. The Project is under development more than 2 or 3 years. Now I am refactoring all old components to be created with the latest ES6 features.

The problem was there are some components which are pure JS functions for example

```
function Index({ a, b, c }) {
   return .....
}

export default connect(....)(Index)
```

They are one of the main components which cause the message

**This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves**

Thanks!